# How much does it cost if someone falls ill before take-off?

Tags: airline-operations, cost

A month or so ago, I flew from LHR to Australia, via Doha, on a Qatar Airways A380. Just as we were about to enter the runway at LHR, the captain announced that someone had been taken ill on the plane, and we'd be going back to the gate. That delayed take-off by (I think) about an hour, and required topping up the fuel tanks.

How much would this have cost the airline? Are there any circumstances where they would pass the cost onto the passenger who fell ill?

Comment: Considerably less than once you're in the air.

Comment: Your question about passing costs to the passenger might get a better response on travel.SE.

Comment: they'd almost certainly pass the cost on to the passenger if (s)he were found to have been trying a prank rather than it being an actual medical emergency.

Comment: A medical emergency is an emergency for which the cost should not be a parameter in the decision process.

Comment: The cost is passed to the customers, but divided among all flight, not just the ones that had illness onboard.

Comment: @WayneConrad, actually the cost is divided among those who take future flights. Since the cost of _this_ flight went up, the (thin) profit margin went down so future tickets will cost ever so slightly more to make up for it.

Comment: @ManuH, I never thought it would be a factor in the _decision_. I assume, however, that the airline has (self-)insurance, which impacts their costs. I could see a scenario where the airline's insurance company might want to pass the cost onto the traveller's insurance company. It'd be bad PR, but that's not stopped other airlines from doing stupid things.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I do agree and was pretty sure you though like that. I wanted to add this warning (greatly improve by your mention of insurance) for newcomers without aviation safety culture.

Comment: @FreeMan, Actually... past, present, or future, these sort of things are just absorbed and baked into overhead as the cost of doing business. (i.e. Airline executives don't sit around and review individual instances and apply their specific cost overruns: "*Gentlemen, John's Doe's little puking incident last week means we need to bump LAX to SEA by $11.37 per seat for the next 90 days to recover..."*) All customers pay a ticket price that hedges against incidents like this. Your correction of Wayne Conrad's comment wasn't really necessary. Just like this comment isn't really necessary... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to get an exact figure, there are fuel prices, the time to taxi, gate charges, medical charges for the removal of the person on the plane, staff costs, and more. I can't guess at most, however from a fuel cost perspective I know for the 747-400 at LHR many airlines use a figure of 1000kg in planning for APU and taxi to takeoff. An A380 would be more, I'd ball park a figure of 1380kg for the airbus based on the MTOW difference (a rough approximation). 1380kg is about 1750 liters, at about .50 GBP per liter that's about 875GBP, or about 1150USD at today's conversions. So the fuel alone would cost somewhere around a grand, I'd imagine you could comfortably double that by the time all is said and done.

As for passing the cost on to the customer I've never heard of that being done for a genuine illness, or even a suspected illness. I don't know if they could if they wanted to, however I cannot imagine them trying it, the reputational fallout would be enormous.